# Git Revert Not Making Necessary Changes

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am trying to run

```
git revert ########
```

and get a merge conflict. After I resolve the merge conflict in my editor (PyCharm), I run

```
git revert --continue
```

and then get the following message

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

You are currently reverting commit ########.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Yet, if I view my repository at the time of the targeted commit to revert to, I can clearly see differences in my requirements.txt file (and I'm sure there are other files as well). If I run

```
git revert --continue
```

again as suggested in the response/prompt, it will present the same response again,

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

You are currently reverting commit ########.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git revert --continue")
  (use "git revert --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: After resolving the conflict in an editor/3-way merge tool, you then need to run `git add ...` to tell git the conflicts are resolved. Until the files are added `git status` will show "both modified" and `git ls-files -u` will show the contributing sources.

Comment: Would I need to push this as well? `git add .` followed by `git revert --continue` gives me the same response of nothing to commit. I can choose "yours" or "theirs" and I've ben choosing "yours" before hitting "resolve" in my editor. I don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: As it turns out, what I was actually looking for was git reset. I did not realize git revert is only for a specific commit.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, what I was actually looking for was git reset. I did not realize git revert is only for a specific commit. This is why I could see changes in other files at that same position for the git commit that were not getting changed.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question you asked. This answer simply points out that you asked a question for which you no longer need an answer to, at least not right now.